# ncat stops listening after 100 UDP packets

Tags: linux, networking, netcat, udp, packet

I'm continuously sending packets to a UDP server after 1 second. To listen for UDP packets:

```
ncat -klup 1234 --sh-exec "cat > /proc/$$/fd/1"
```

However, after printing 100 packets, nothing else prints. With Wireshark I can see that packets are still being sent but on the server side nothing prints.

```
$ ncat -klup 1234 --sh-exec "cat > /proc/$$/fd/1"
Hello Server!
1 Send
2 Send
3 Send
4 Send
5 Send
6 Send
7 Send
8 Send
9 Send
10 Send
11 Send
12 Send
13 Send
14 Send
15 Send
16 Send
17 Send
18 Send
19 Send
20 Send
21 Send
22 Send
23 Send
24 Send
25 Send
26 Send
27 Send
28 Send
29 Send
30 Send
31 Send
32 Send
33 Send
34 Send
35 Send
36 Send
38 Send
39 Send
40 Send
41 Send
42 Send
43 Send
44 Send
45 Send
46 Send
47 Send
48 Send
49 Send
50 Send
51 Send
52 Send
53 Send
54 Send
55 Send
56 Send
57 Send
58 Send
59 Send
60 Send
61 Send
62 Send
63 Send
64 Send
65 Send
66 Send
67 Send
68 Send
69 Send
70 Send
71 Send
72 Send
73 Send
74 Send
75 Send
76 Send
77 Send
78 Send
79 Send
80 Send
81 Send
82 Send
83 Send
84 Send
85 Send
86 Send
87 Send
88 Send
89 Send
90 Send
91 Send
92 Send
93 Send
94 Send
95 Send
96 Send
98 Send
99 Send
100 Send
101 Send
```

Regardless of how many times I try is always stops after 100 packets.

Comment: You should also try [`socat`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/socat/socat.1.en.html) instead of nc/ncat. You'll discover it has waaay more options. Also if your UDP source port didn't change, ncat wouldn't fork a new process per packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stated in the [ncat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ncat.1.html) man page

> ```
> -m numconns, --max-conns numconns (Specify maximum number of
>    connections)
>        The maximum number of simultaneous connections accepted by an
>        Ncat instance. 100 is the default (60 on Windows).
> ```

100 is the default maximum number of connections. It can be modified with the `-m` flag.

Comment: I misunderstood that argument I assumed it meant the number of different clients that can connect and send packets simultaneously.

Comment: Glad I could help! ;)

Comment: how to set to unlimited number of connections until I manually stop nc?